# Android JPEG to Bitmap to JPEG

Tags: android, bitmap, size, jpeg, reduce

i have a problem with the image size saved. Let's say i have a JPEG that is 1028 x 960 and i will read the file into a bitmap and do some editing and save it as a JPEG again. The image will be 514 x 480. Is there anything i can do so the size remain unchanged?

This is my code when i read the file :

```
private void choosePhoto() {
    generalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    generalIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(generalIntent, CHOOSE_PHOTO);
}
```

and this

```
if (requestCode == CHOOSE_PHOTO) {
    cleanUpImageView();
    tempImageUri[1] = data.getData();
    editPhotoImg.setImageURI(tempImageUri[1]);
}
```

And this is the codes for saving file :

```
private void savePhoto() {
    if (editPhotoImg.getDrawable() == null) {
        Toast.makeText(EditPhoto.this, "No Photo Edited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        try {
            String filePath = getOutputMediaFile(RESULT).getPath();
            editPhotoImg.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = editPhotoImg.getDrawingCache(true);

            b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            Toast.makeText(EditPhoto.this, "Image saved to: " + filePath,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(EditPhoto.this, "Invalid File Path", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Image quality was also lost but i think maybe it can't be helped. But i truly hope that at least the size will not reduce. Thank you for the help in advance. I appreciate it.

Comment: Where do you get picture from?gallery?

Comment: Are you using a parameter "inSampleSize = 2" anywhere? Because both your height and width have been halved.

Comment: Nayoso, ya I am getting photos from gallery. Is it different if I get it from somewhere else? Because I allow them to choose the picture from anywhere on the photo.

Comment: Royston,  I didn't specify the inSampleSize anywhere. But is the default one =2? For that I am not sure but will setting the insamplesize solve my problem? :)

Comment: PNG format might be best for lossless compression